# What is the need of converting an image into numpy array?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I was watching a tutorial on a facial recognition project using OpenCV,numpy, PIL.
During training, the image was converted into a numpy array, what is the need of converting it into a numpy array?

THE CODE:

```
PIL_IMAGE = Image.open(path).convert("L")
image_array = np.array(PIL_IMAGE, "uint8")
```

Comment: The array representation has pixel values as numpy matrix which can be used as features for any machine learning algorithm.

Comment: Are there any functions in OpenCV which take an image as argument?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Just about every OpenCV function uses an image in a Numpy array as parameter.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Then, it should be obvious why the image needs to be converted to a Numpy array, if that is what the functions accept.

Comment: In the 2 lines of code you've show? There's no real reason for it. However, the actual program presumably has some further statements, which invoke function(s) that expect a numpy array as an input.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR;** OpenCV images are stored as three-dimensional Numpy arrays.

When you read in digital images using the library, they are represented as Numpy arrays. The rectangular shape of the array corresponds to the shape of the image. Consider this image of a chair

[image]

Here's a visualization of how this image is stored as a Numpy array in OpenCV

[image]

If we read in the image of the chair we can see how it is structured with `image.shape` which returns a tuple `(height, width, channels)`. Image properties will be a tuple of the number of rows, columns, and channels if it is a colored image. If it is a grayscale image, `image.shape` only returns the number of rows and columns.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("chair.jpg")
print(image.shape)
```

> (222, 300, 3)

When working with OpenCV images, we specify the `y` coordinate first, then the `x` coordinate. Colors are stored as `BGR` values with blue in layer 0, green in layer 1, and red in layer 2. So for this chair image, it has a height of 222, a width of 300, and has 3 channels (meaning it is a color image). Essentially, when the library reads in any image, it stores it as a Numpy array in this format.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is rather simple:

With Numpy you can make blazing fast operations on numerical arrays, no matter which dimension, shape, etc. they are.

Image processing libraries (OpenCV, PIL, scikit-image) sometimes wrap images in some special format that already uses Numpy behind the scenes. If they are not already using Numpy in the background, the images can be converted to Numpy arrays explicitly. Then you can do speedy numerical calculations on them (convolution, FFT, blurry, filters, ...).